# Scrape error "element script embeds close tag"

Tags: python

I am scraping Yelp reviews using Python. I always got the Exception `element script embeds close tag` at

```
tree = html.fromstring(br.open(url).get_data())
```

and a url is like this:

```
url = "http://www.yelp.ca/biz/le-bernardin-new-york?start=1249"
```

which refers to review #1249 for restaurant le bernardin. I always have this problem after scraping around 2,000 reviews, no matter which restaurant I am scraping from. I added sleeps between each review but it did not help. If I restart the program from the same review, there will be no error. 
What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: which python libraries are you using for scrapping? `urllib`, `urllib2` or some other? Which kind of objects are `html` and `br`? How do you import/initialize/instantiate them? We can't help without knowing this information.